# Monitoring Beanstalkd performance

Tags: performance, beanstalkd

I have started to look into [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) for queuing my Jobs for processing, I have following questions though that I request answers to:

1. Where can I enable Beanstalkd logging and where is the log file ?, so that in the event of issues from Beanstalkd , I can actually identify what the issue was.
2. What kind of performance impact is there if file sync for jobs is enabled and used?
3. How can I monitor the health of Beanstalkd and what are the vital health parameters of Beanstalkd that can be accessed via the running Beanstalkd application?

Please reply me with relevant answers/links.

thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Currently logging is not possible, there is a feature request [here](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/issues/260).
2. File sync for jobs must be enabled to have persistent mode. The impact is minimal, you don't notice it. You can still process 10k ops/second without any performance hit.
3. You can check out [beanstalk admin panel](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console) it provides some numbers, that would help you at the beginning. But you have graph, nagios plugin available on the tools page.

You can check out other [beanstalkd tools](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/Tools) here.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what strategy would you recommend for the cases where Beanstalkd process crashes out before file sync actually is done, will the jobs in queues be considered lost ? is such a scenario possible ? if yes what's the possible recovery route for in memory jobs?

Comment: I never heard about this scenario. We run beanstalkd with several years uptime, and no incident. Anyway you can backup regularly the binlog file to a safe storage.